# Prevent negative animated value on scroll

Tags: react-native

I have header collapsed on scroll event. On ios scroll offset value can be negative and it cause problem.

[image]

Is there any way to prevent animated value being negative?

Here is my code

```
const ScrollYDiffClamp = Animated.diffClamp(positionY, 0, 60);

const headerTranslate = ScrollYDiffClamp.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: [0, -1],
});

return (
 <>
   <Header style={{transform: [{translateY: headerTranslate}]}}/>
   <Animated.ScrollView
      onScroll={Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: positionY}}}], {
     useNativeDriver: true,
   })}>

   </Animated.ScrollView>
 </>
```

)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can disable bounces on your Animated.ScrollView

```js
bounces={false}
```

or you can add additional interpolate and fix this issue

```js
const headerHeight = 50;
const clampedScrollY = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
    extrapolateLeft: 'clamp',
  });

  const diffClampScrollY = Animated.diffClamp(clampedScrollY, 0, headerHeight);

  const translateY = diffClampScrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, headerHeight],
    outputRange: [0, -headerHeight],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
```

Comment: This definitely worked for me. The common reason why we don't want to disable "bounces" is to be able to use the refreshControl prop in our ListViews, android has no problem doing this, so we would like to keep it the same for iOS most times. But this is only 1/2 of the problem. Anyways thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your interpolation configuration.

```js
extrapolate: "clamp"
```

Comment: i tried it but doesnt work, also tried `extrapolateRight`, `extrapolateLeft`

Answer (score 0):

Oleskii's answer worked for me, the only issue I was having was on the bottom the issue that this solved on the top was still happening.  Just adding more to the max height seems to have resolved the issue though. Something like:

```js
const diffClampScrollY = Animated.diffClamp(clampedScrollY, 0, headerHeight + 300);
```

the bouncing that happens in the ScollView seems to be covered with 300 added to the max output of the diffClamp